# Reconfiguring table column data in rows via SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Forgive me if this is answered someone else; I have a working table I'm trying to rearrange in MySQL via a query. The working table looks like this:

```
+-------+------+-------+
| Sport |Points| Name  |
+-------+------+-------+
| A     |   53 | Alex  |
| A     |   22 | Jim   |
| A     |   11 | Josh  |
| B     |   63 | Joe   |
| B     |   22 | Rich  |
| B     |   10 | Frank |
+-------+------+-------+
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to output the table in this format through an sql query:

```
+-------+-----+---------+-----+---------+-----+---------+
| Sport | 1st | 1stName | 2nd | 2ndName | 3rd | 3rdName |
+-------+-----+---------+-----+---------+-----+---------+
| A     |  53 | Alex    |  22 | Jim     |  11 | Josh    |
| B     |  63 | Joe     |  22 | Rich    |  10 | Frank   |
+-------+-----+---------+-----+---------+-----+---------+
```

Usually I would not format my table this way, but it makes it easier for me to display the top 3 players per sport via PHP. Any efficient suggestions are absolutely welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: I really recommend you just fetch the rows with `ORDER BY Sport, Points DESC` and then arrange them in columns using PHP code. That will be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate the row numbers using a variable based on the descending order of score for each sport.

```
select sport,points,name,
,@rn:=case when sport=@prev_sport then @rn+1 else @rn end
,@prev_sport:=sport
from t
join (select @rn:=1,@prev_sport:='')
order by sport,points desc
```

Then use conditional aggregation to get the top 3 scores per sport on one row.

```
select sport
,max(case when rnum=1 then points end) as p_1
,max(case when rnum=1 then name end) as n_1
,max(case when rnum=2 then points end) as p_2
,max(case when rnum=2 then name end) as n_2
,max(case when rnum=3 then points end) as p_3
,max(case when rnum=3 then name end) as n_3
from (
select sport,points,name
,@rn:=case when sport=@prev_sport then @rn+1 else 1 end as rnum
,@prev_sport:=sport
from t
join (select @rn:=1,@prev_sport:='') r
order by sport,points desc
) x
group by sport
```

In case of ties in points, a name is arbitrarily picked up.

To break the ties to show the lowest or highest name, the above query can easily be changed to include an ordering on name.

```
select sport
,max(case when rnum=1 then points end) as p_1
,max(case when rnum=1 then name end) as n_1
,max(case when rnum=2 then points end) as p_2
,max(case when rnum=2 then name end) as n_2
,max(case when rnum=3 then points end) as p_3
,max(case when rnum=3 then name end) as n_3
from (
select sport,points,name
,@rn:=case when sport=@prev_sport then @rn+1 else 1 end as rnum
,@prev_sport:=sport
from t
join (select @rn:=1,@prev_sport:='') r
order by sport,points desc,name --change it to name desc if the highest name should be shown in case of ties
) x
group by sport
```

Comment: This is a great answer and worked fantastically; it processed much quicker than any of the solutions I was trying.

I tend to shy away from user-defined variables because they do not work with views in MySQL, however I'm beginning to see the importance of them and am trying to change my work style to incorporate them more often.

Thank you again!